# Display members with same taxonomy using Views

Tags: 8, views

Users have a "school" term reference field. When user visits his own user page, I want him to see his classmates listed.

For example, imagine that I have 3 students from the same school. When student A `id:4` visits `user/4`, I want all student B and student C listed.

I can do this on term's page, `term/10`, but I could not figure out how to do it on user's page.

I believe it would have to be configured through contextual filter but I could not find a way yet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view block of users and show all the required fields.
2. Add a contextual filter for school.
3. Now here ideally we need some way to dynamically get the school id
   of the current logged in user. But we only get these kinds of values:[image]
4. So in order to dynamically get the term id of the user's field. we can either write a custom hook `hook_views_pre_view` See its [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.2.x) and modify the correct `$arg` by loading the current user and getting the user's selected term for school.
   or
5. Create a custom views argument plugin, or use this module : https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_value

Answer (score 0):

This is a common request to list sibling nodes in Views. You can search to find other examples.

In your case:

1. Create Views listing all Users with Page or Block Display
2. Add a Relationship **Content referenced from field_school** (or however it's called in your particular case), you can require it, this introduces the School into the Views.
3. Add another Relationship **Content using field_school**, set it to **use the Relationship from the previous step**, you can require it. This is the reverse direction, pointing to all children that are pointing to this parent (School).
4. Add the Contextual Filter **User ID** and configure it:
   Relationship **field_school** (the second one)
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **User ID from route context**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **User ID**
5. If this is a Block Display place it on Child nodes and it will show other children that relate to the same Section. Don't forget to configure both the Block Visibility and Contextual settings.

   If you're using a Page Display change your **Path** setting to `user/%user/[schoolmates]` (change the brackets to what you like) and **Menu** to `Menu tab` "[Your tab name]". This will add a Drupal tab on the user profile pages that shows this Views, listing content that is related to the terms chosen by the user in their profile settings.
6. To remove the current user from the list add another Contextual filter **User ID** and configure it with these options:
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **User ID from route context**
   `More`
   **Exlude**

To check the Contextual filter with Views Preview, enter the ID of the Users you want to simulate, and enter it for each Contextual filter.

If you have both the contextual filter that identifies siblings and the one that excludes the current user from the list (and the Child ID is 24) enter `24/24`.

If you want to see all the results, unaffected by Contextual filters enter `all/all`.